# Broken Sword 5 - how to skip through walking / run

Tags: broken-sword-5

In *Broken Sword 5* it takes time to watch the protagonists walk slowly and position themselves correctly to interact with other objects and people. Is there a way to fast forward those sequences, or at least run instead of walk? I tried a few things like double clicking, holding the shift key and such but none of them works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

It's hard to prove a negative, but:

1. [The *Broken Sword 5* manual](https://revolution.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/BS5_Manual_UK_NEU.pdf) (edited by Revolution Software) only talks about walking, not even "moving to". There is no mention of running, and it's not like the game's mechanics are extra lengthy to describe.

   > MOVING AROUND
   >
   > To move George or Nico around, simply move your mouse pointer to **the point you want them to walk to**, and click the left mouse button. If they can’t exactly walk to that point, then they will get as close as possible – so don’t worry about being too precise.
   >
   > Some areas are larger than the screen you are playing on. In these cases, **as your character walks towards the edge of the screen**, the camera will pan to reveal more of the location.
2. It's not included in the tutorial either.
3. This is one of the very few features that the game really, really lacks. It's been seven years since the game came out; you'd think if anybody had found a way to run, the mechanic would have been shared and be easily findable by now.